# Upgrade webpart from 2007 to 2013 Issue

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-server, migration

I have a custom webpart which worked in SP 2007 but after the migration to 2013 it failed to work properly. There was no visual display. The custom webpart is very old and the source code is no longer available for it.

Any ideas on what I can do? I'm trying to avoid rewriting it. It does not use any third party controls. Just straight custom code.

UPDATE:

I used reflector and the only issue is that it uses v12 of the SharePoint.dll.

Is there any way around this without redeveloping?

Comment: Can you share the code or at the very least it's function?

Comment: Even if you find the issue, you are going to have to rewrite it to be able to package/deploy it. Bite the bullet and start rewriting the web part in a new project and get it into source control.

Comment: I used reflector and the only issue is that it uses v12 of the SharePoint.dll

Comment: Saying you have to "rewrite" is a bit too strong word. Most of it will probably just be copy pasting. It's not like they've really changed anything essential in that front during the last N versions.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck. Perhaps check the SharePoint log and windows event viewer to see if it's reporting anything fixable. Also, edit the page and check the web part properties. Perhaps there's a custom property that isn't set correctly due to the upgrade? Or, perhaps there is a list that the web part is using for configuration values? For example, perhaps the web part uses a property or a custom list to determine a URL, which is now invalid due to the upgrade?